# Displaying images in Javascript corresponding to buttons

Tags: javascript, html

So far I am able to get a button to create a new image element, but that is about it. I need to have one button display one image, and another button to display a different image in it's place. All of the answers have lead to me to results that just display the new image below the first.

Must be in plain Javascript and HTML.

```
function f1() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "test1.png");
    img.setAttribute("width", "256");
    img.setAttribute("height", "256");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "pic");
    document.body.appendChild(x);}

function f2() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "test2.png");
    img.setAttribute("width", "256");
    img.setAttribute("height", "256");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "pic");
    document.body.appendChild(x);}
```

Each script is tied to an onclick button in HTML, and it sort of works. I can get my images to appear, but each button click creates a new element and I believe it's due to the append statement, but I don't know how to get it to show up otherwise.

Figured it out: by initializing the img variable outside of the functions and having the buttons modify the source of the image. It works fine.

Comment: What do you have so far? Please show your Javascript/HTML/CSS

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to be writing your own code. We'll help you figure out the bits you're having trouble with, but we won't write it for you. So have a bash at it, and show us what you've got, and we can then give you some pointers.

Comment: I've added my JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a global variable to test if you've already created one of the images or test if the image already exist before creating it. The global variable approach is probably faster and only needs little changes to your code:

```
var img1 = false;

function f1() {
    if (!img1) {
        img1 = document.createElement("img");
        img1.setAttribute("src", "test1.png");
        img1.setAttribute("width", "256");
        img1.setAttribute("height", "256");
        img1.setAttribute("alt", "pic");
        document.body.appendChild(img1);
    }
}
```

Of course it would be better to have only one function doing that (just pass the img src as an argument, since they both do the exact same thing). Then you could store the img variable in an array or assign an ID to the created images and then test the DOM for this ID before creating/appending them again.

Comment: Nice way t do it. With the variable it should indeed go faster than the way i described it. My function should work right out of the box though :p.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently adding new elements with each click. What needs to happen instead is that in the event where an image is already created, the image should change. You could do this by using the following function.

```
function changeImage(src,width,height,title){
    vid = document.getElementById('changingImage');
    if(!vid){
        vid = document.createElement('img');
        vid.id = changingImage;
        body.appendChild(vid);
    }
    vid.src = src;
    vid.style.width = width;
    vid.style.height = height;
    vid.setAttribute('title',title);
}
```

This function first tries to find an image with a certain ID. If that isn't found, it will be created. After the image is located it's attributes and styles will be applied. Just call this function with the right parameters. This way you do not need 2 functions.